# Delayed next call from behaviorSubject when multiple notification - Angular, Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular app, I have a **state** **stored in a service** as a **BehaviorSubject**, when **data comes** from server I call the **next** function to update data and to notify all subscribers.

**PseudoCode:**

```
   ajaxCall_1 -> updateData(response2)
   ajaxCall_2 -> updateData(response2)
   ajaxCall_3 -> updateData(response3)
   ...
    
private data$:Observable<any>;
public updateData(newData){
var currentData = data$.value;
data$.next({...currentData , ...newData})
}
```

Since a lot of components subscribed to that BehaviorSubject, I think it can cause some performance issue when my app is loading: on load there's a lot of notifications from server and each time next function is called components are rendering.

Do you think if I delayed the call to the next after something like  500 ms I will see performance improvement?
What will be the rxjs way to delay the next call?

Comment: Do u need all calls? Seems like it is updating frequently. Then u need to store final state there? then u can use switchmap

Comment: Yes I need all calls. How  switchmap can help me there?

Comment: No SwitchMap only keep the latest call If u need all calls, need to use MergeMap there. What is the purpose of catches all the call. Actually have no idea about ur scenario. If so u might need to change the structure here. Maybe use the queue to enqueue states and dequeue thing like that

Comment: I added some pseudocode, maybe clearer now?

Comment: Using `unsubscribe` maybe help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A performance impact will be from the components that subscribe to that BehaviorSubject rather than itself.

Anyway you can use the [delay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delay) operator to delay the next call, something like this:

```
private sub$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
public data$ = this.sub$.pipe(delay(500)));

public updateData(newData){
  var currentData = sub$.value;
  sub$.next({...currentData , ...newData})
}
```

Comment: Delay would not reduce the number of calls. It'll only postpone them (all). Example if you trigger 2 calls at 10ms and 20ms, with a delay(500) they'll happen at 510ms and 520ms. You're just shifting the issue by 500ms here. I think OP is looking for either debounce, debounceTime, audit, throttle, windowTime, buffer, bufferTime or bufferCount (but he has to be the one choosing the correct operator as he didn't describe how he wants to solve this)

Comment: @maxime1992, seems you understand my problem, do you have an answer for me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can decide how often (say once per second), your updateData function is called.

What I've done here is buffer all your calls for a second, then reduce the buffer into a single object, then emit that object to updateData.

```js
merge(
  ajaxCall_1,
  ajaxCall_2,
  ajaxCall_3,
  ...
).pipe(
  bufferTime(1000),
  filter(buffer => buffer.length > 0),
  map(bufferedNewData => bufferedNewData.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ({...acc, ... curr}), {}
  ))
).subscribe(updateData);
```

On the other hand, it might make sense to display nothing until the first set of calls all complete. This might make the initial load more predictable. That's only a slight change:

```js
forkJoin([
  ajaxCall_1,
  ajaxCall_2,
  ajaxCall_3,
  ...
]).pipe(
  map(loadNewData => loadNewData.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ({...acc, ... curr}), {}
  ))
).subscribe(updateData);
```